# SwiftUI: Unexpected Animation when using a non @State var

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I need some help. I created the following reusable view, let's call it `MyCustomCapsuleView`:

[image]

Nothing special, just a `Text` with a `Capsule` in the background. This view will have a different look when the user turns it on.

[image]

When the user turns it on, `MyCustomCapsuleView` padding should increase to 17 to account for the extra space needed for the new look. Also, it should:

1. Scale up and back
2. Start wiggling

When the user turns it off, `MyCustomCapsuleView` padding should go back to 3, as the extra room is not needed anymore. Also, it should:

1. Stop wiggling
2. Scale up and down, again

I was able to get a functional version of this, but the paddings are not working properly. When `MyCustomCapsuleView` is wiggling, the paddings go back and forth between 3 and 17 (see the yellow background).

[image]

1. Any ideas what am I doing wrong? How can I achieve the behaviour I need? Note: Since this view is reusable, I need that the "turned off" version of my view keeps padding = 3. I will use it across different parts of my app and only in some places the "turned on/off" version will be available, and only in those places the padding for my view is 17.
2. Why the rotation (wiggle effect) looks so weird? I tried different anchor unit poi.ts (center, trailing, etc) and none of them seems to give me a good look.

Thanks for your help!

Here's my code:

```
struct MyCustomCapsuleView: View {
    @State private var scaleUp = false
    
    var showRemove: Bool
    private var fillColor: Color { return Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4745098054, green: 0.8392156959, blue: 0.9764705896, alpha: 1)) }
    private var foregroundColor: Color { return Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1019607857, green: 0.2784313858, blue: 0.400000006, alpha: 1)) }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            Text("Hello World!")
                .foregroundColor(foregroundColor)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .background(
                    ZStack {
                        Capsule(style: RoundedCornerStyle.continuous)
                            .fill(fillColor)
                        Capsule(style: RoundedCornerStyle.continuous)
                            .stroke(foregroundColor, lineWidth: 2)
                    }
                )
            
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .overlay(
                    Image(systemName: "multiply")
                        .resizable()
                        .padding(7)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                )
                .offset(x: 15, y: -15)
                .scaleEffect(showRemove ? 1 : 0, anchor: UnitPoint.topTrailing)
                .animation(.spring(response: 0.3, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0), value: showRemove)
        }
        .padding(showRemove ? 17: 3)
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .scaleEffect(scaleUp ? 1.2 : 1)
        .animation(.spring(response: 0.3, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0), value: scaleUp)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(showRemove ? 7 : 0), anchor: UnitPoint(x: 0.10, y: 0.0))
        .animation(showRemove ? .easeInOut(duration: 1.15).repeatForever(autoreverses: true).delay(0.3) : .easeInOut(duration: 0.15), value: showRemove)
        .onChange(of: showRemove, perform: { value in
            if !scaleUp {
                scaleUp = true
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false) { _ in
                    scaleUp = false
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

struct Test: View {
    @State var showClose = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            MyCustomCapsuleView(showRemove: showClose)
            Button("Turn On/Off") {
                showClose.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of tricky. Currently, your `.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)` animation is animating not only the `rotationEffect`, but also the `padding`. To prevent this and use the `repeatForever` *only* for `rotationEffect`, I think the way to go is with [explicit animations](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-an-explicit-animation) and 2 separate `@State`s.

- Explicit animations let you specify which properties to animate.
- 2 separate `@State`s allows a different animation for each var.

  - `@State var showClose` is a one-time animation for creating a larger `padding()` and the scale-up animation
  - `@State var rotating` is the `repeatForever` animation for the rotation

Here's what your `Test` struct would look like:

```
struct Test: View {
    @State var showClose = false
    @State var rotating = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            MyCustomCapsuleView(showRemove: showClose, rotating: rotating)
            
            Button("Turn On/Off") {
                print(showClose)
                withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.3, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0)) {
                    showClose.toggle()
                }
                withAnimation(rotating ? .easeInOut(duration: 0.15) : .easeInOut(duration: 1.15).repeatForever(autoreverses: true).delay(0.3)) {
                    rotating.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, modify these lines in your `MyCustomCapsuleView`:

```
var showRemove: Bool
var rotating: Bool /// add this
```

```
/// replace your `ZStack`'s modifiers with this:
.padding(showRemove ? 17: 3)
.background(Color.yellow)
.scaleEffect(scaleUp ? 1.2 : 1)
.rotationEffect(.degrees(rotating ? 7 : 0))
.onChange(of: showRemove, perform: { value in
    if !scaleUp {
        scaleUp = true

        /// btw, why not just `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(.now() + 0.1)`?
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false) { _ in
            scaleUp = false
        }
    }
})
```

Result:

[image: Animation as expected, first gets larger, then rotates around center]